# How to get the url with freemarker template?

Tags: java, freemarker

I want to fetch current URL with free marker.
Also i need to split the url href part.Is there any method similar to JavaScript method **location.href**.

*Ex: http://www.barcamp.com/homepage/overview.go.*
Here i need to fetch the url & also to the split the url and get its as **/homepage/overview.go**

Please help us on this issue

Comment: Fetch the current URL from what context? Are you using the FreemarkerServlet?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the current URL falls outside FreeMarker's jurisdiction, since it's independent of Servlets and HTTP. It's up to the Web application framework if and how it exposes that information for the templates, so check the documentation of the framework.